# PDFlib TET get name of the current color

Tags: java, pdflib

My need is to read the color of a text with PDFlib TET.

As a basis I'm using this PDFlib example: https://www.pdflib.com/tet-cookbook/tet_and_pdflib/search_and_replace_text/

Before both `result.add(new rectangle(...))` calls I'm trying to read the color like this:

```
    String csname = tet.pcos_get_string(doc, "colorspaces[" + tet.colorspaceid + "]/name");
    if ("Separation".equals(csname)) {
        String type = tet.pcos_get_string(doc, "type:colorspaces[" + tet.colorspaceid + "]/colorantname");
        System.out.println(type);
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("name", type)) {
            System.out.println(tet.pcos_get_string(doc, "colorspaces[" + tet.colorspaceid + "]/colorantname"));
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately `tet.colorspaceid` is always 0.

But the correct colorspaceid is 6 (with "correct" = the index of the color the text actually is written with). I know the indexes because I iterated over all colorspaces like this and for i=6 the system prints the name of the intended color:

```
    String type = tet.pcos_get_string(doc, "type:colorspaces[" + i + "]/colorantname");
    if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("name", type)) {
        System.out.println(tet.pcos_get_string(doc, "colorspaces[" + i + "]/colorantname"));
    }
```

What do I need to do for tet.colorspaceid being the id of the colorspace of the currently found word fragment?

Or am I completely wrong and TET reads the color somehow else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - the solution is method `print_color_value` in this example: https://www.pdflib.com/tet-cookbook/text/glyphinfo/

Just copy method `print_color_value`, return `csname` (or `colorantname` in the if blocks) and rename the method to e.g. `getColorValue`.

If needed throw away the formatter stuff.